# OSX Stuck - Window manager is responsive, but can't create any process

Tags: macos

Shortly (seconds) after booting, the OS (10.6.8) becomes unresponsive. Not a single process can be created, but the window manager is responsive - I can switch focus between existing windows and some already loaded programs - e.g. Terminal, Finder, etc but I cannot run any new processes - opening a browser, or even executing "ls" from command prompt yields no results.

There are no obvious CPU hogs - I managed to quickly run "top -u" with no high CPU util at the point it gets stuck (at one point the top utility stops refreshing, I suspect it spawns a new process for each refresh).

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error, the correct answer proved to be such: [disable IPv6](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/3923564).
The OSX machine started to freeze when I switched internet connection and WiFi router.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory and it is pretty easy to test...

I think the permissions on your Admin account are corrputed, not allowing you to spawn new processes.  How it happened, I don't know.

However, you can create *another* admin account by booting into *Single User Mode*

1. Reboot/Power On
2. Press and Hold Command-S
3. When you boot, you will be in a Terminal window at the root (#) prompt
4. Type the following:

   ```
   rm /var/db/.applesetupdone
   ```
5. Reboot by typing:

   ```
   reboot
   ```

When your Mac boots, you will be presented with the Welcome screen.  Follow the prompts to create a new Admin account.

The problem should go away.